# Sanity check for a simple calculation involving Dirac spinors and matricies

Tags: dirac-equation, spinors, dirac-matrices

I've been doing some research related to the Dirac equation and its solutions. To help make sure I understand what's going on, I've done some simple calculations involving planewave solutions. I'm using the matrices $\alpha_k = i\gamma_0\gamma_k$ where the $\gamma$'s are standard Dirac matrices. The (un-normalized) spinor part of a positive energy spin up planewave I'm using is

$u(\vec{p}) = \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
p_3/(E+m) \\
\frac{p_1+ip_2}{E+m}
\end{pmatrix}$

where $\vec{p}=(p_1,p_2,p_3)$ is the planewave's momentum vector and $E$ is its energy. Here are some sample calculations:

$\bar{u}\alpha_1u = -\frac{2ip_1}{E+m}$

$\bar{u}\alpha_2u = 0$

$\bar{u}\alpha_3u = \frac{2ip_2}{E+m}$

where $\bar{u}=u^\dagger\gamma_0$. I get results consistent with these using spin down and/or negative energy spinors. The first and third of these make sense since, after normalization, the $\alpha$'s are picking out various components of momentum. What doesn't make sense to me is $\bar{u}\alpha_2u = 0$ because that makes it seem like the $p_3$ component isn't part of the story. Expectation values of quantities involving the $\alpha_k$ then don't depend on $p_3$ at all. Why should one of the components of the planewave's momentum be physically irrelevant?